# Test/ check speed of Marklogic REST endpoints ingestion?

Tags: python, rest, marklogic

Hi Markloggers out there,

I try to load documents into Marklogic using the REST endpoint.

To speed things up I implemented a multi process client that posts documents to the default REST endpoint for ingestion of documents. Now I bump into some performance issues that I need to investigate.Documents ingested are geospacial kml type xml.

I am aware of the fact that mlcp is the defacto standard to ingest data in ML but for various reasons I use a python client with the requests lib to talk to ML.

I have a single threaded solution, works great but is slow
ingesting 42000 documents takes roughly 7 1/2 minutes

If I run the multiprocessing variant on my laptop INSIDE eclipse it takes 3 minutes, no errors

If I run the same script from the commandline it takes roughly 1 minute and 15 seconds but I hit the following error on the client side:

```
Connection aborted. error 99 Cannot assign requested address
```

which seems a low level socket error. nothing in the logs of Marklogic...

ML is on the same machine as the python script (my laptop sony vaio i7 8 cores 8GBram SSD disks)

On another machine, (dev server 4cores) the script runs fine.
Single thread 10:55 multithread(4 cores) 3:18 so significant improvement.

Question: How can I test/check the ingestion speed of the REST endpoint in Marklogic?

Comment: Can you check the access log for the MarkLogic appserver's port after running the multiprocessing version on the command line? That will tell you whether you're making a connection.

Comment: One hypothesis would be that, on the laptop system, the multithreaded loader opens connections faster than the connections return to the pool and so runs out of connections. Eclipse might be slowing things down to where the pool can keep up, and the dev sever might support more connections or free them faster. If diagnostics confirms that the number of open connections increases steadily, you could see whether throttling helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with OS-level performance monitoring, on the client and the server. See if there's a clear bottleneck on the disk, CPU, or network. If there is, you may need to reduce the number of active threads for optimal performance.

You might be running out of [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).